# Handle exceptions / HTTP status code based on exception types

Tags: c#, exception, custom-attributes

I'm trying to throw some exception, catch it in a `HandleException` attribute and return it properly to the client.

Here is an example:

```
[HandleException(Type = typeof(UserNotFoundException), Status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
[HandleException(Type = typeof(LoginFailedException), Status = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
public UserProfile Login(UserCredentials userCred)
```

In my `Login()` function I either throw a `UserNotFoundException` or `LoginFailedException`.

My `HandleExceptionAttribute` looks like this:

```
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode Status { get; set; }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var ex = context.Exception;

        ResponseHelper.CreateException(Status, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What I want is to be able to handle what kind of exceptions is going to be thrown and handle it properly in an attribute, where I specify the HttpStatusCode.

The problem, with this code, is that the top-most attribute is always called. So even if the exception is a `LoginFailedException` I always get `UserNotFoundException` and 404 code returned to the client.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, it looks like you're going to need to do some filtering in your `OnException` method, so that you verify that the exception you got matches the exception you intended that instance of the attribute to handle.

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{
    var ex = context.Exception;
    if(typeof(ex) == Type)        
        ResponseHelper.CreateException(Status, ex.Message);
}
```